# How do you deal with runny nose?

Tags: personal-care

When I have a runny nose, I usually go through a couple of tissue boxes. It is very annoying. For some reason, blowing doesn't work. What can I do?

I don't necesarrily need to cure it, just make it less annoying.

Comment: Mucinex dries up your sinus, so maybe that is a good solution for you. One thing I do when I have a head cold is use saline solution, tilt my head back, fill my sinus, let it sit for a minute, and then evacuate it into the tub or bathroom sink. Saline works two fold: first, it really breaks up mucus; second, it is antibacterial.

Comment: `There isn't a hack answer to this problem —`  I agree. There are a lot of health-related treatments and consumer products to help alleviate the unpleasantness, but dealing with this type of health ailment isn't really within the scope of this site. .

Comment: Drink more water. 95% of the time this solves it, so it was the problem. Now, just make it a habit. The histamine response is actually related to dehydration, you can research this. Also, the body is trying to hydrate the incoming air so your lungs don't dry up. Asthma is actually your body's response to a life threatening emergency: if your lung tissues dry out, you will die. This has been documented by medical research. Do yourself a favor and drink enough water.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a hack answer to this problem - if you've got a runny nose because you're getting a cold, it should pass within a day or so. If you frequently have a runny nose that goes on for some time, or keeps recurring, you've probably got allergic rhinitis which might be a hay fever response at certain times of year, or some other allergic response to something you're frequently exposed to or are eating (dairy, for instance). Consult your doctor, you may need to take antihistamines or use a nasal spray to control it.

Answer (score 0):

You could neti pot your nose. They sell them at most pharmacies. You simply flush your nose out with a salt water solution. It cleans alot of the gunk out of your nose.

Also as was mentioned, could be allergies. Have you seen a doctor about it?

Answer (score -1):

Stick wads of tissue up your nostrils.

A con of this is it is harder to breath. If only one nostril is acting up, just put it in that one. A con of this is the tissue is itchy, and it causes the other nostril to run more.

This is far from an optimal solution.